# i want to know what app an icon belongs too... how can I find out

Tags: applications, notification-icons

I would like to know how I find what app an icon relates to on top left of android phone please. Thanks :)

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Looking for the second icon</sup>

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot, to clarify the exact icon you are reffering to. It may be some kind of notification, but we can't be sure if no there is no screenshot

Comment: Usually on most devices, long-pressing the notification might tell the underlying app.

Answer (score 1):

Tap and hold on the icon, it become draggable.

In the top(or bottom) you will see 2 options **remove** if it is on home screen or **uninstall** if it from the menu and **app info**. Drop the icon on **app info** and it will bring you the corresponding page in settings.